# How do I set series name in legend in GCP metrics chart for multiple metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Log-based metric `smsSent` of type=count with two labels `error` and `ok` (representing amount of sent messages that went sideways or were sent ok, it can only be all ok or all error).

I want to display this metric in a chart with two series, one for `ok` and other for `error`.

In Metrics explorer, I create chart, I add first metric, add filter for `error > 0` and Legend template "error", then I "Add another metric", add the the same `smsSent` metric, add filter for `ok > 0` and Legend template as "ok"

The chart now works as expected, but issue is with the legend - I can see that in the legend there are two lines, both Name=error. I expect to see one line with Name=error, and the other with Name=ok.

According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/working-with-legends#descr_template) this should work, but it always seems to show only first label in legend for all series.

How can I display different legend labels for each series?

[First metric detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnOrp.png)

[Second metric detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHicT.png)